# I want to pass a portion of touch event to my super view in my view controller how to do that?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller. In that view I have placed a view to the frame.bounds. And with in that view there is a table view as sub view.

The first view is a page view controller. I have to pass my portion of touch event to the super view of my table view. How to pass touch event to the page view controller which is a super view on the table view controller?

Here I'm attaching the output of my view controller. Here you can see the empty space but it is a table view with background color as clear and it has an offset value of 130 for the first cell. So it looks like table view is starting with an offset of 130. How to pass this portion of touch to my page view controller so that I can swipe page view controller?

Please look in to the two images so that you will understand my plan.

[image: First Look]

[image: Second look]

In the first look situation you can see a horse image which is a page view controller so within this area touch should work to swipe the horse image. If I scroll it will look like second image you can understand the actual height of the table view (I have added offset 130 with clear background color So the table view starts with some space and while scrolling the cells will look like image 2).

I hope you understood the situation. I have used method

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
}
```

no use cause this is a viewcontroller but not a view.

So give me few ways how to achieve this.

Comment: Create a custom delegate to share the information between two view  controllers

Comment: It is not two different view controllers It is only one view controller

Comment: do you want mutually exclusive events ?

Comment: Yeah means if I tap on the cells and scroll up or down it should work, and if I tap on the horse image and swipe it, then swiping should work

Comment: I want to transfer touch event to page view controller (which is a super view of table view) for that empty portion  Is that possible ? It is working for android but How to do it in ios ?

Comment: it all depends on how you have laid out the layout for the viewcontroller. You should keep the two views separate and add both of them with the right constraints to the the view controller as subviews

Comment: there is no issue with the constraints , it is the matter of passing portion of touch to the super view is that possible ?